# Jquery on form submit after next page load

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, alert

I am trying to write an alert jquery function using jquery alert.  What I basically want to do is submit a form, wait for the page to reload, and then show an alert.  However, I am having trouble trying to organize this.  Here is my code.

```
$("input.auto").click( function() {
 $('#form').on("submit", function(){
   $(document).ready( function() {
      jAlert('Example of a basic alert box in jquery', 'jquery basic alert box');
   });
 });
});
```

Right now the alert doesn't wait for the page to reload and just shows right after clicking.  How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

You edit code like below:

```
$("#form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jAlert('Example of a basic alert box in jquery', 'jquery basic alert box');
});
```

Comment: I am sorry but it doesn't work.  It just prevents the page from reloading and the form from submitting.

Answer (score 0):

After you click, the page is already loaded so it will present the alert.

You should include a hidden field in the form which gets submitted. Then call the alert if the hidden field is passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered a great jQuery plugin called jQuery Form.  It turns your form into an ajax form.  Extremely simple and works like a charm.
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('form').ajaxForm(function() { 
            jAlert('Example of a basic alert box in jquery', 'jquery basic alert box');
        }); 
    });
```